# Two physical servers, same IP, nginx setup

Tags: nginx

I have two physical servers that are connected to same network and using No-IP service, I made them dynamic DNS resolving.

One server is **xx.ddns.net**, second server is **yy.ddns.net**.

I want to approach this:

Point CNAME to **xx.ddns.net** for:
*test1.example.com*

Point CNAME to **yy.ddns.net** for:
*test2.example.com*

I already have test1.example.com pointing to CNAME **xx.ddns.net** and it works, but when I did set up **yy.ddns.net** on the other server, I got 404 error on Nginx.

This is part of Nginx configuration for **test1**:

```
server {
  server_name xx.ddns.net test1.example.com
}
```

The same I set up for **test2**:

```
server {
   server_name yy.ddns.net test2.example.com
}
```

It's funny because now, I'm getting 404 on both **XX** and **YY**, but when I access **test1.example.com** it works - site loads. But, when I try to access **test2.example.com** I also get 404 error.

Can someone advise me how to use No-IP and Nginx with same IP on two different physical server machines? Thank you.

Comment: who hosts nginx ?

Comment: yy should be the host. For now, XX is the host, but that should be changed to YY

Answer (score 1):

If the two servers have "same IP", I assume you mean the external IP and they are behind NAT (router) in some local network.

Just because you have set them to use different domain names, doesn't change the fact that all browsers will resolve those to single IP, and that is the IP they will talk to in order to request website data.

Which website gets loaded in this situation depends on your router settings. E.g. if you do port forwarding from port 80 to local IP `xx.ddns.net` machine, then, provided that both CNAMEs still resolve to the same IP address, both websites will load from `xx.ddns.net` machine.

In order to be able to serve sites from different servers in your LAN to external visitors, you need your router to be able to inspect the `Host` request header and forward proxy requests to appropriate local IP. It is highly unlikely that your router supports this.

So the other way is choosing one of the NGINX servers to serve double purpose of hosting either of the domains and do the `proxy_pass` to the other domain/server when it's being requested.